# SQL trigger error - invalid trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm using pl\sql developer and I have a report table with a number(38) ID column.

I want to keep track of all updates for this table so I created another table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE reportUpdate (report_id number(38), updatedate number(32));
```

And I created a trigger:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER BeforeUpdateReport 
BEFORE 
UPDATE ON REPORT 
FOR EACH ROW 
Begin 
   INSERT INTO reportUpdate 
   Values(old.ID,sysdate); 
END;
```

And when I run it, I get an error, saying: `trigger 'SYSTEM.BEFOREUPDATEREPORT' is invalidand failed re-validation`.

Can someone please help

Comment: You most probably got a `trigger created with warning` when you created the trigger. Do a `show errors` and you'll see what is wrong with the code

Comment: Tags belong in the tags, not in the title.

Comment: Where do u see tags in the title?

Comment: @Shmuli: Before the edit, you had "(Oracle)" in the title. The consensus on StackOverflow is, that tags shouldn't go in the title, but in the tags field.

Comment: You might need to change `CREATE TABLE reportUpdate (report_id number(38), updatedate date);` But not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show errors` after you see `compiled with warnings`, or query the `user_errors` view to see what is wrong later.

One obvious thing is that you haven't prefixed the `old` reference with a colon:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER BeforeUpdateReport 
BEFORE 
UPDATE ON REPORT 
FOR EACH ROW 
Begin 
   INSERT INTO reportUpdate 
   Values(:old.ID,sysdate); 
END;
/
```

It's also better to specify the target table fields in the `insert` statement:

```
   INSERT INTO reportUpdate (report_id, updatedate)
   Values(:old.ID,sysdate);
```

But you have `update_date` defined in your table creation script as `number(32)`, which doesn't make sense. As @realspirituals pointed out, it should be:

```
CREATE TABLE reportUpdate (report_id number, updatedate date);
```