# Oracle Trigger after delete

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to do a trigger delete after I delete a row in databaseA employee table, databaseB author table with the same employeeid will be deleted as well. But after several attempts, it keep prompting trigger with errors without specifying what is the error. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
      DELIMITER //
      CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_delete 
      AFTER DELETE on databaseA.employee
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
      DELETE FROM databaseB.author
      WHERE databaseB.author.employeeid = old.employeeid
      END;
      /
```

Comment: Do `show errors`, or query the `user_errors` view, to see the actual compilation errors. By 'database' do you mean 'schema'? You're missing a colon before `:old` but not sure if that's the only issue.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after DELETE statement; you even need `:old` instead of `old`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23561094/266304) if that is the only error.

Comment: I added the colon WHERE databaseB.author.employeeid = :old.employeeid but still getting error.

Comment: Did you add the semicolon to the end of the delete statement too? Use `show errors` to see what is wrong, as I said before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the posters above are create.  You must finish the actual delete statement with a semicolon ";".  Also, "old" and "new" must be prefixed with a colon ":".  In addition, the trigger may have some issues with authorization depending on grants, synonyms and authorizations.  If I were to guess, the syntax problems are the first issues.  If, after that, you still experience problems, you may have a grant issue.

Comment: Yup is the semicolon that is causing it. Thanks guys!